# How to count the empty cells in a dataset?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have been trying to determine the number of empty cells in the whole dataset.

I have used `sum(is.na())` but, it did not work. It gives the complementary result of `sum(complete.cases())` gives/shows the complete rows (without any empty cells). I have also tried `sum(dat$exampleColumn != "")`. However, I want the number of all empty cells. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Example data

```
 Age  ZipCode  Smoke  Activity 
  25    13020    No   3x week
  35    08740    Yes  NULL
  15    NULL          5x week
  42             Yes  
  14    42859    N/A  2x week
```

There are just three empty cells in this example. I want to reach this value.

[image: A snapshot of the dataset after uploading to R.]

[image: Output of dput]

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset along with the number you would call "number of empty cells"? Not clear what you mean by empty cells. `NA`s? 0-length strings (`''`)? Strings of blanks (`' '`)? `NULL` values in list columns? Some combination of these?

Comment: This edit does not answer the question, as it is a printout of the data and not the data itself. Please use dput(data_name_here)

Comment: This is a toy data but, mostly represent my data. I cannot put my data here because of the privacy issue.

Comment: Ok. But I am not asking for my own good, I'm asking as a way of telling you it isn't possible to answer this question without knowing what "empty cells" means.

Comment: "Empty cell" means that the cell is left blank. Nothing in the cell.

Comment: There is no such thing

Comment: I have included a snapshot of the dataset after uploading to R. Let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you copy/paste the output you get from `dput(data_name_here)` into the question?

Comment: The output is the data. It is huge. It puts the name of each column and ends with `class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 292735L)`

Comment: If it's too big you can share the first 20 rows only, with `dput(head(data_name, 20))`, just make sure the first 20 rows have some examples of the "empty cells"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complete.cases() function counts cases with missing values, but there are none in the dat provided. First we have to put it in a format that we can read:

```
dat <- read.csv(text=" Age,ZipCode,Smoke,Activity 
  25,13020,No,3x week
  35,08740,Yes,NULL
  15,NULL,,5x week
  42,,Yes,
  14,42859,N/A,2x week", as.is=TRUE)
```

All the cases are complete because none have missing, i.e. NA values:

```
sum(!complete.cases(dat))
# [1] 0
```

We want the number of blanks in the data, not the number of cases with blanks:

```
sum(dat=="")
# [1] 3
which(dat=="", arr.ind=TRUE)
#      row col
# [1,]   4   2
# [2,]   3   3
# [3,]   4   4
```

But this data will be a challenging because a stray blank character: " " will be read as a field that is not blank.

In the future, create your data in R and use dput(dat) to paste it into your question:

```
dat <- 
structure(list(Age = c(25L, 35L, 15L, 42L, 14L), ZipCode = c("13020", 
"08740", "NULL", "", "42859"), Smoke = c("No", "Yes", "", "Yes", 
"N/A"), Activity = c("3x week", "NULL", "5x week", "", "2x week"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

We cannot be certain that this is exactly what your data should look like since blanks separated by blanks are not easily identified and the character strings might be stored as factors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am uploading an excel file using `read.xlsx(data)` function. Let me take a snapshot of the dataset after uploading to R. Let me know if I am doing something wrong or something wrong with the data.

Comment: No this does not help at all. We cannot run R commands on your picture. Use the dput() function and copy/paste the text into your question. Have you tried my suggestion on your data?

Comment: Yes, I have tried and have received just `NA`. Let me put the data to `dput`.